# Unicode in django 2

Tags: python, django

I am used to using `print` to print the django model object that I define in `__unicode__`, but it seems that no longer works:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    """GMT-03:00 Palmer"""
    return "GMT-%s %s" % (self.offset_time, self.name)



>>> t=Timezone.objects.all()[0]
>>> print (t)
Timezone object (Andorra)
 >>> t.__unicode__()
'GMT-02:00 Andorra'
```

How would I call the "print" method, like it was previously done in django, to return the unicode method?

Comment: You can use `print(unicode(t))`. Note however that in Python-3.x, `unicode(..)` has been removed, since `str` now supports unicode strings.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem got it -- thanks for your continued help on these django questions!

Comment: @DavidL, what version of Python and Django are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening here is that `print()` needs a string representation of the object. This happens by first looking for a `__str__()` method and falling back on the `__repr__()` method if that doesn't exist.

If there's no `__str__()` method, the final fallback is `object.__repr__()` at the end of the inheritance chain. Or in the case of django model objects, `django.db.models.Model.__str__()` which gives you the output seen in the question.

In django < version 2.0, the `__unicode__` method was used instead of `__str__` in template rendering. The reason was python 2 compatibility. In current versions of django, use `__str__()` instead.

Answer (score 4):

According to Django's [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.__str__), you should define your model's `__str__()` method to get a string representation of it. Although, in older versions of Django and using python 2, you used to do it by defining `__unicode__()`.

Answer (score 0):

`__unicode__` should be implemented when you are using Python 2 in order to have a string representation of your model.

If you are using Python 3, you should implement `__str__` instead. [From the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.__str__), implementing this method allows you to have a human-readable representation of the model.